# Remove Insignificant decimal places when converted to string (C#)

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a property which has decimal datatype let's say "Interest" then I have another property of string type let's say "InterestString".

**Properties**

```
 public decimal Interest { get; set; }
 public string InterestString { get; set; }
```

I want to assign the value of Interest to InterestString so I did the following. For example lets assume Interest has a value of 4 (without decimal places):

```
InterestString = Interest.ToString();
```

If the conversion finished my `InterestString` becomes "4.000" but the value of my Interest is only 4 without .0000.

I want to retain the format even after conversion. How can I get rid of those insignificant decimal places?

If I do something like this

```
InterestString = Interest.ToString("N0");
```

It will give me InterestString="4";`But what if I have Interest 4.5? This will give me`InterestString = "5"` (rounded to ten).

If I do `Interest.ToString("N2")` that would give me still 2 insignificant decimal places. The behavior that I want is remove the insignficant decimal places.

Please help.

Comment: Did you try `Interest.ToString("0.#");`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think `System.Decimal` has a `Normalize` method, which is basically what you want. If you know how many decimal places you want *at most* you can use:

```
string x = Interest.ToString("0.######");
```

with as many # signs as you're interested in. Only significant digits will be filled in:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ShowInterest(4m);    // 4
        ShowInterest(4.0m);  // 4
        ShowInterest(4.00m); // 4
        ShowInterest(4.1m);  // 4.1
        ShowInterest(4.10m); // 4.10
        ShowInterest(4.12m); // 4.12
    }

    static void ShowInterest(decimal interest)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(interest.ToString("0.#####"));
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you manage to edit your answers and it doesn't show that the post was edited?

Comment: @Guillaume: Edits within the first five minutes of an answer being posted aren't shown.

Comment: Thanks this is indeed the output that I want.

Comment: How can we acheive the same thing without hardcoding number of #?

Comment: @Pushkar: You'd probably need to create the format string dynamically - either as a custom format string (as above) or a standard format string where the number of digits is just specified as a number. But I don't think there's a *programmatic* way of doing it.